# Errors in Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

In Eclipse, when I edit a class, all other classes are automatically checked for errors. For instance, when I comment out a function in class A I see all classes that refer to the function marked red in the project explorer.

In Android Studio when I do the same, no class is checked for errors. The project explorer shows no errors. It is only until I open a class that the errors become visible for this specific class.

How can I have the same behaviour in Android Studio as in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your gradle.properties:

`org.gradle.daemon=true`